# call a function with optional and name arguments in another function

Tags: python, function, arguments, call, option-type

How can we do function implementation for the following?

For optional and named arguments we write function in following way.

```
def funct(*args, **kwargs):
    for arg in args:
        print “arg =”, arg
    for key in kwargs.keys():
        print “arg[{0}]={1}”.format(key, kwargs[key])
```

If I want to call this function inside another function of same protocol, how can I implement?

```
def funct2(*args, **kwargs):
    # call funct() above
    funct(????????)
```

So is there any way to call the first `funct()` with optional arguments inside the new `funct2()` with the same type of optional arguments?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for calling a function is basically the same as when defining the function. So your `funct2` would look like:

```
def funct2(*args, **kwargs):
    # call funct() above
    funct(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here are the Python docs covering the subject: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists